# Nodemailer Message Configuration Missing 'From'

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

So my nodemailer transport is working fine (for the most part) however, I am now trying to embed an image.  The issue is now that I have the additional 'attachments' option in my mailOptions object, it is throwing the following error.

```
Error: 'from' parameter is missing
```

this is strange since I most definitely have a from parameter. Emails send fine without an attachment. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var mailOptions = {                             
    from: 'confirmation@donotreply.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Account verification',
    html:'<p>Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link' + confirmationLink + '\n\n' + '<img src="uniqueqr@qr.example" alt="something went wrong"/>',
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'qr.png',
        path: '../path/to/my/file/qr.png',
        cid: 'uniqueqr@qr.example'
    }],
};
```

Comment: Make sure you close ``<p>`` tag in the html and get rid of last comma after closing square brackets

Comment: appreciate it, no luck though, I've tried all combos of commas and no commas etc, closing </p> doesn't make a difference, but a good catch overall. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const mailOptions = Object.freeze({
        from: 'confirmation@donotreply.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account verification',
        html: '<p>Hello</p>,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link' + confirmationLink + '\n\n' + '<img src="cid:uniqueqr@qr.example" alt="something went wrong"/>',
        attachments: [{
           filename: 'image.png',
           path: '/path/to/file',
           cid: 'uniqueqr@qr.example'
       }]
    });
```

note the `cid` inside `img` tag